# My Profiler using Byte Buddy agent does not stop monitoring some tests

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to collect execution time from all methods of an application called by their tests using Byte Buddy. However, sometimes, it takes much longer than expected. For example, when I run the test described below without the Byte Buddy agent, it takes a few milliseconds to run. When I start with the agent it runs without ending and I need to force stop. It occurs in several test cases from different projects. What could I be doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Agent:

```
class PerfrtProfilerAgent {

    public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        String[] agentArgs = arguments.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
        final String packName = agentArgs[0];

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
        .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
        .type((ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith(packName)))
        .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
                .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                .intercept(Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(AgentArguments.class, arguments).to(TimerAdvice.class))
        ).installOn(instrumentation);
    }
}
```

TimerAdvice.java

```
package perfrt.profiler;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

    
public class TimerAdvice {   
        
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static OnMethodEnterReturn enter(@Advice.Origin String method, @AgentArguments String agentArguments) {
        String[] agentArgs = agentArguments.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
        
        OnMethodEnterReturn onEnterValues = new OnMethodEnterReturn();
        onEnterValues.setPackageName(agentArgs[0]);
        onEnterValues.setCommitHash(agentArgs[1]);
        onEnterValues.setIdRun(Integer.parseInt(agentArgs[2]));
        onEnterValues.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String className = parseClassName(method);
        System.out.println("onEnter - Class: " + className + " method: " + method);
        onEnterValues.setIdMethod(1);
        return onEnterValues;
    }
    
    @Advice.OnMethodExit(onThrowable = Throwable.class)
    public static void exit(@Advice.Origin String method
            , @Advice.Enter OnMethodEnterReturn onEnterValues   
    ){
        String packName = onEnterValues.getPackageName(); 
        String className = parseClassName(method).replace(packName, "") + ".java";
        long start = onEnterValues.getStartTime();
        long end =  System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = end - start; 
        String returnedType = "teste";
        System.out.println("onExit - Class: " + className + " method: " + method + " start: " + start + " end: " + end + " duration: " + duration + "retValue:" );
    }
    
    public static String parseClassName(String method) {
        String className = null;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]*\\(");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(method);
        if (m.find()) {
            String methodName = (String)m.group(0).toString();
            
            String[] methodAux = methodName.split("\\.");
            if(methodAux.length > 0) {
                className = methodAux[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < methodAux.length-1; i++) {
                    className += "." + methodAux[i];
                }
            }else {
                className = methodName;
            }
        }
        String last = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        className = last + ".java";
        return className;
    }
}
```

The complete code of the agent is at [perfrt-profiler2](https://github.com/paulorfarah/perfrt-profiler2).

The steps to reproduce one example of the situation are:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/commons-bcel
2. cd commons-bcel
3. mvn -Drat.skip=true install (requires maven)
4. wget -O junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0-M1.jar https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/junit/platform/junit-platform-console-standalone/1.9.0-M1/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0-M1.jar
5. wget https://github.com/paulorfarah/perfrt-profiler2/raw/master/perfrt-profiler2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
6. java -javaagent:perfrt-profiler2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar=org.apache.bcel.,cbbed9ec41c70469cab42a584e205b96c0f964fc,483 -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.0-M1.jar -cp .:target/test-classes/:target/classes:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-5.8.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.8.2/junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-params-5.8.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.8.2/junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.8.2/junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.12.1/jna-5.12.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.12.1/jna-platform-5.12.1.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar -m org.apache.bcel.HandleTestCase#testBranchHandle

In the last step, you need to replace "/home/user/.m2" for the correct maven cache folder of your computer.

Comment: Did you try to take s thread dump in such a case? It sounds like s deadlock.

Comment: Not yet, I'll check it out right now! Thanks for the suggestion...